# on click div appear slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm facing a problem in my website please help me
this is my website link http://istinye.superpaket.org

```
 $(function() {
    $('li.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When i click on any nav menu button div appear very fast. i want to appear the div slowly not fast. for example when i click on "Menü" button, the div menu appear but very fast i want to this effect slowly. Thanks in advance...

Comment: increase the animation time by increment `1500`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the animation duration

```
$(function() {
    $('li.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 5000, 'easeInOutExpo');
        //--^--------- change animation duration on here in milliseconds
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/animate/#duration

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you set time delay i.e 4000
Hope its working.

  $(function() {
      $('li.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
      var $anchor = $(this);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 4000, 'easeInOutExpo');//Change here
     event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you can change the duration `1500` to `6000` or something

```
$(function() {
    $('li.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 6000, 'easeInOutExpo');  //change animation duration            
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```